# How to get case values from a file while using switch case in java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

My code looks something like

```
switch(string){

case "mangoes":

case "apple":
}
```

I wish to store the values of mango and apple in a file, and read from it into the case so that I can modify the file to modify the case values.

into:

```
switch (string) {

case valuefromfile:

case value2fromfile:
}
```

Comment: `switch` works with constants only, you might compare values from a list using `equals` and read the list dynamically.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y-Problem. What are you trying to solve here?

Comment: My case values might change after a few months. I do not prefer an if-else-if, It will get too long. is there any other method? enum maybe?

Comment: Maybe you should insert a "configuration" layer. User an Enum for your case and leave it as is. BUT: Make a configurable mapping between your keywords and enum items. So you could for example use something like getEnumKeyFor(string). Sounds like just shifting the problem to another place but: You could read a map from your configuration file that says for example "mangoes:enMGO;apple:enAPP" after some months you get told to treat Bananas just as you did apples. Then you would simply change your configfile to "mangoes:enMGO;banana:enAPP" ... I hope you see what I mean.

Comment: Is it possible to use getEnumkeyFor(String) as an item in enum? i'm guessing you mean getEnumkeyFor(String) is a function that returns a string.

Comment: No, I meant you give it a string, it looks it up in a map (that has been filled by reading your configuration) and returns the appropriate Enum Key that will lead to the desired case being entered. You could put it inside the Enum class, but personally, I would rather make a little "helper" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. `case` expressions must be `constant` expressions. They shouldn't be dynamic.

Go with `if-else-if`

If you are worrying about more if-else-if statements,  add all your dynamic values in a list and just check that the list contains your passed string.

Comment: there is alot of cases so an if-else-if might be too long. do you know any other method?